# Hide controls - use play / pause

Tags: video.js

Is there a way when you hide controls and still be able to pause / play video ? 
I've seen that when controls are visible the player works fine and reported no other problem.

I tried to find an answer on docs but no luck. So is there a way to do this ?

Many thanks and great work here!

Answer (score 0):

Video.js works like the html5 video video element, where if you turn off controls the only way to control the video is through the API. The easiest way to set up what I think you're talking about would be to do the following.

```
videojs('my_video_id').on('click', function(){ 
  if (this.paused()) {
    this.play();
  } else {
    this.pause();
  }
});
```